How to Select rows in a While Loop in MySQL
I have a table (that represent a matrix) in MySQL as follows:
CREATE TABLE matrices
(
  matrix_id varchar(50),
  `row` INT,
  `column` INT,
  `value` float(24)
);

And I insert following values into the table to define a matrix:
-- INSERT MySQL
INSERT INTO matrices 
(matrix_id, `row`, `column`, `value`)
VALUES
('m1', 1, 1, 1),
('m1', 1, 2, 2),
('m1', 1, 3, 3),
('m1', 2, 1, 4),
('m1', 2, 2, 5),
('m1', 2, 3, 6);

I use the following query to display the matrix in such a way that all the values of a specific row of matrix should appears on first row and for the second row of matrix it should appear on second row
-- loop for printing
SET @counter = 1;
SET @m_id = 'm1';
SET @r = (SELECT max(`row`) from matrices where matrix_id = @m_id);
WHILE @counter <= @r DO
BEGIN
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`value`, SEPARATOR ' ') FROM matrices where
    matrix_id = @m_id and `row` = @r
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END WHILE;

But It seems I have a issue in my While LOOP for MySQL.
What is the correct syntax of While Loop to use here.
Note: I am using MySQL on onecompiler.com.
I want the output to look like this:
1 2 3
4 5 6


Not really what you asked but you may want to look into doing it a different way. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/274960/transpose-rows-data-into-columns-in-mysql for how it can be done without the loop.

@Simon Goater - In MySQL there is no direct WHILE loop syntax like in other programming languages. Instead, you typically use a WHILE loop with a stored procedure or a function. Would you like to do this in a stored procedure?

@BerndBuffen yes I would like to do it in procedure form, morover what about postgress, how to do it in direct loop in postgress, I also want to do it in postgress.

I would avoid loops in database queries when ever possible. When I need a loop, there is in 99% the cases an design failure in my database.

you can try this:
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`value` ORDER BY `column` ASC) as `result`
FROM `matrices`
GROUP BY `row`
ORDER BY `row` ASC;

Here your sample: click here

I want to do it via loop, in both MySQL and postgress, I am literally stuck at it, can't figure it out how to write it using while loop, this is very important for me to do it via while loop, please help me here, please, I am so tired, feels like I am so dumb.

please help me learn this. give me answer in while loop too. Please, I just can't express how frustrated I am right now, please give me answer in while loop

In MySQL, you typically don't use while loops for row iteration; instead, you leverage SQL's set-based operations. Here's a corrected approach to achieve what you want:
SET @m_id = 'm1';
SET @r = (SELECT max(`row`) FROM matrices WHERE matrix_id = @m_id);
SET @counter = 1;

WHILE @counter <= @r DO
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`value` ORDER BY `column` ASC SEPARATOR ' ') 
    FROM matrices 
    WHERE matrix_id = @m_id AND `row` = @counter;
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END WHILE;


no its not working

Can you share how you are using it and what part is not working

I think better your merge your both post @obisoftgeek
and delete the new post...

Try this updated query
SET @m_id = 'm1';
SET @r = (SELECT MAX(`row`) FROM matrices WHERE matrix_id = @m_id);

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`value` ORDER BY `column` ASC SEPARATOR ' ') AS 
row_values
FROM matrices 
WHERE matrix_id = @m_id
GROUP BY `row`;

